# Windows Add/Remove Programs: Uninstalling Java 6, Update 26 "Fatal Error During

Tags: java, windows-xp

Installation"I have Windows XP. I am trying to uninstall JAVA 6, Update 26. I first deleted the actual program files. But when I went to Add/Remove Programs on my Control Panel, it was still there!

I clicked on the Remove button for Java. A Windows Installer box pops up saying "Please wait while Windows configures Java" and then "Fatal Error During Installation". I tried redownloading JAVA 6-26, but it didn't work because I already had JAVA "installed".

I tried downloading JAVAra, and now, there's a Java Auto Updater program on the Add/Remove Programs page that doesn't even have a "Remove" program button!

Could someone please, please help me get rid of Java 6-26 and the Auto updater?? They aren't viruses, are they?!? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

With deleting the actual programm files you most likely deleted the uninstall programm of java (along with the rest of java).
What you see in the control panel are registry entries that link to the now non existend uninstaller.
To get rid of those wrong entries i recommend you use [CCleaner](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner), which checks your registry for invalid entries. That should clean up the list in Add/Remove programs in your control panel.

And no, they are not viruses. But if you want to be absolutley sure on that, i recommend running a virus scan.

Comment: CCleaner unable to remove that instance from Add/Remove Programs